# how to create a temporary expiring url for forgotten password functionality in Codeigniter (PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a forgot password functionality, where in I need to have a temporary url pointing to reset password page which is valid for a limited period of time (eg: 3 Hrs)

Comment: You need to be slightly more informative than that.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a random hash
2. Save it with the current timestamp to your database
3. Create an URL with this hash and send it to the user
4. when the URL is called, check if `currentTimestamp < (savedTimestamp + (3 * 3600))`